# Package with web-services to integrate Salesforce with a 3rd party

Tags: integration, webservices, package

I`m going to create a package that other Salesforce users can install to integrate with a 3rd party system. When package is installed 3rd party knows nothing about new system where that package was installed for example login details to connect to that new environment.

Is there a good way of providing such information, or each time the package is installed someone will need to do it manually i.e. Visualforce page or button press to send login details to a 3rd party? Also are there any best-practices for that?

Thanks

Comment: So, do you want to send some current SF org credentials to 3rd party application?

Comment: @kurunve Yes, so 3rd party will be able to use SF web-services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement InstallHandler interface and add this class to a package. You can make an async callout and pass required data to third party service